# enum values passing as arguments in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums

i have an enum.

Example:

enum events

{

```
MOVE_UP = 0,
MOVE_DOWN,
MOVE_RIGHT,
MOVE_LEFT,
```

};

i want to pass particular enum value as function arguments. for example:

my method definition is

- (void) invokeEvents:(enum events)events withMessage:(NSDictionary*)message;

while calling this method i am passing arguments like:

[self invokeEvents:MOVE_UP|MOVE_DOWN|MOVE_RIGHT withMessage:message;

while checking the received parameter **events** is value is always last value of list of MOVE_UP|MOVE_DOWN|MOVE_RIGHT values.  MOVE_RIGHT 2 as per enum value.

but i want all the values like "MOVE_UP|MOVE_DOWN|MOVE_RIGHT" equal 0, 1 and 2. 
how can i pass the parameter so that i can get all values.

kindly give suggestion for my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had the same problem before, and after doing a fair bit of research, could not find a way to do it.

Comment: @Liang lets see there is any solution from others, then what u did for this problem or which way, i means what alternative way u used for solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your enum to:

```
{
MOVE_NONE = 0
MOVE_UP = 1<<0,
MOVE_DOWN = 1<<1,
MOVE_RIGHT = 1<<2,
MOVE_LEFT = 1<<3,
};
```

So you can pass parameters exactly as you want: `MOVE_UP|MOVE_DOWN|MOVE_RIGHT`.

And in `invokeEvents:withMessage:` check

```
if(events & MOVE_UP)
{
}
if(events & MOVE_DOWN)
{
}
...
```

.

Comment: how can i store this value in array. for example: events = MOVE_UP|MOVE_DOWN means value of the events is MOVE_UP = 0001 and MOVE_DOWN = 0010. just assume only 4 bits now the value is 0011 i want to store this value. which data type is fit for this in objective-c.

Comment: It's NSInteger that may be wrapped NSNumber object.